# Why template class assignment operator can use "templated copy constructor" to assign different type

Tags: c++

I have a `template<class T> class Container {}`.

While doing some code experiments, I realised that when I call the assigment operator (`operator=()`) with a different type (i.e. passing a different template parameter to my `Container` template class), it compiles.

It turns out that this is possible because I also have a "templated copy constructor" (I'm not sure what would be the proper name for this) which is called whenever I call the `operator=()` with a different argument type.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Container {
    
    public:
        Container() : data() { }

        Container(const Container &c) : data(c.data) {
            std::cout << "COPY CONSTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
        }

        // This is what I call a "templated copy constructor".
        // If I remove this, the operator=() does not compile with a different type
        template<class U>
        Container(const Container<U> &c) : data(c.getData()) {
            std::cout << "TEMPLATE COPY CONSTRUCTOR??" << std::endl;
        }

        Container &operator=(const Container &c) {
            std::cout << "assignment operator" << std::endl;

            if (this == &c)
                return *this;

            this->data = c.getData();
            return *this;
        }

        const T &getData() const {
            return this->data;
        }

    private:
        T data;
};

int main() {

    Container<int> c1;
    Container<float> c2;

    c2 = c1; // Assigning a Container<int> to a Container<float>

    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles without any errors. If I remove the "templated copy constructor" the compiler gives me this error:

```
test.cpp:41:5: error: no viable overloaded '='
        c3 = c1;
        ~~ ^ ~~
test.cpp:18:14: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Container<int>' to 'const Container<float>' for 1st argument
                Container &operator=(const Container &c) {
```

Can someone explain why this happens and what exactly does the "templated copy constructor" do? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: parameters declared like const Container &c does implicit casts. Your constructor is a converting constructor. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor

Comment: Fun fact: If you change `data(c.getData())` to `data{c.getData()}` you also get a compile error (because you are performing a narrowing conversion there)

Comment: [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/b705e43d) might help, in your case `c2 = c1;` is seen as `c2.operator=(Container<float>(c1));`.

Comment: The real question is, do you really want an ability to silently convert a container of anything to a container of anything else?

Comment: The question is, why it implicitly uses the "converting_constructor" to resolve the type for the operator= overload? I cannot find in the documentation where is mentioned that the operator= overload in a template uses de converting_constructor to resolve the type.

Comment: @Jarod42 i just saw the cppinsights link and now I understand it. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a function call. The parameter type is `Container<A>`. The argument type is `Container<B>`. There is a conversion constructor that converts one to the other. All boxes checked, the call is legal. The function happens to be named `operator=` but this is irrelevant, the conversion ctor will do that with any function.  So the question is,  do you want this *everywhere*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @Jarod42 said in the comments. I used [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/s/b705e43d) and realised that the compiler is seeing `c2 = c1` as `c2.operator=(Container<float>(c1));`, so I suppose it is simply looking for a conversion constructor (what we called a "templated copy constructor" earlier), to see if there is any known way to cast one type to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator=` only accepts a `Container<T>`, which in the case of `c3` is a `Container<int>`.

Something needs to convert `c1` from a `Container<float>` to a `Container<int>`. The copy constructor is doing that.

Comment: Is it really a copy-constructor here? the types are different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I kind of realised that already, but could you explain the "internal workings" of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well. What exactly does "class" mean? Or in other words, why we need operator overloading for a class?

When we overload an operator, we define how to operate data belonging to the same class. How do we compare them? Let's declare and implement an overloaded operator '<' for it to solve this problem.

```
class Stone
{
public:
    bool operator<(const Stone& anotherStone)
    {
        return this->_weight < anotherStone._weight;
    }

    float _weight;
}
```

You see, the class of stone can then be compared. Similarity, we define the assignment of the same class of things by declaring and implementing '=' operator.

```
class Stone
{
public:
    bool operator<(const Stone& anotherStone)
    {
        return this->_weight < anotherStone._weight;
    }

    void operator=(const Strong& anotherStone)
    {
        this->_weight = anotherStone._weight;
    }

    float _weight;
}
```

In conclusion, **we overload operators just for manipulating data within the same class**, and that's the usage of operator overloading.

For your code, c1 belongs to class Container and c2 belongs to class Container, they are totally different classes. It makes no sense to define a 'template copy constructor'.

But the compilation complains nothing just because the type 'int' and type 'float' could be converted one another implicitly. If the variable c2 is the type of Container, you will not be lucky like this.

Comment: I do not really understand what this has to do with the question.